# Finding $N$ of a limit of a sequence for an $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

The formula I got for the sum ($\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{2^j}$) is $$A(n) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$$ I want to show that $$\forall \epsilon, \exists N \geq 0 \text{ such that } n \geq N \text{ implies } |A(n) - 1| < \epsilon$$
Now I was able to get the following $$|1 - \frac{1}{2^n} - 1| < \epsilon \implies |-\frac{1}{2^n}| < \epsilon \implies |\frac{1}{2^n}|< \epsilon$$.
How do I go about finding the N required to complete the proof?
So far I have worked the following $$2^n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ How would I go about isolating the $n$?

Comment: Take logs? ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$2^n > \frac 1\epsilon$

$n  > \log_2 \frac 1\epsilon$.

so if $N = \log_2 \frac 1\epsilon$ then

If $n > N = \log_2 \frac 1\epsilon$ then $2^n >2^N = 2^{\log_2\frac 1\epsilon}=\frac 1\epsilon$ and $0 < \frac 1{2^n} < \epsilon$ and $|(1-\frac 1{2^n} )- 1| < \epsilon$.  And so $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (1-\frac 1{2^n})=1$.

Comment: suppose we were allowed to use any methods, could we have proved to formula using limit laws (addition limit law)?

Comment: Well, sure.  $1 -\frac 1{2^x}; x>0$ is continuous so $\lim (1-\frac 1{2^x})= 1-\frac 1{2^{\lim x}}$ but I don't like that abuse of concept treating an infinite limit as a number.  If you can finesse the language and terminology it's okay.  Prove if $b> 1$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} b^x=\infty$ and if $f(x)\to\infty$ prove $\frac 1{f(x)}\to 0$ and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Option:

$\frac{1}{2^n} <\epsilon;$

Binomial expansion:

$2^n=(1+1)^n>1+n(1)>n;$

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t.

$n_0 >1/\epsilon;$

For $n\ge n_0: $

$\frac{1}{2^n}>\frac{1}{n}\le \frac{1}{n_0} <\epsilon.$